# How can I temporarily set $PATH and . (source) a file?

Tags: shell-script, path, posix, source

Consider this. `IFS` is set only in the execution of `read`.

```
IFS='' read -r REPLY
```

However, if I do similar with `.` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source)), the variable will be assigned and changed even after the execution of the line of code.

```
PATH="/new_path:${PATH}" . script.sh
echo "$PATH"         # Value changed
```

Why would this happen? I thought `.`, as well as Bash's `source`, is a command just like `read` or `echo`. Is there any documentation, e.g., *[2.14. Special Built-In Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)*, mentioning this behaviour?

How can I temporarily set `$PATH` and `.` (source) a file, in the POSIX compliant way?

Comment: The entire purpose of the `source` command is to allow the script to make changes to your working environment.  This is stated explicitly in the page you linked to. `$PATH` is not exempt from these changes and oftentimes you want the sourced script to change the PATH.

Comment: @doneal24: I think midnite is asking for a solution that will restore the original `$PATH` if and only if the sourced script did not set it, and otherwise preserve all changes the sourced script makes. In practice, I would just write that as a conditional (i.e. `if [ "$PATH" = "/new_path:${oldpath}" ]; then PATH="$oldpath"; fi`). But that's not *completely* fool-proof because the sourced script could clobber `$oldpath`.

Comment: @Kevin If the sourced script did not set (or change) the PATH, then there is no reason to restore it to the original value. Your solution is also assuming that `new_path` is pre-pended to PATH. Might be better to check with `[[ "${PATH}" != "${oldpath}" ]]`

Comment: @doneal24: You have to restore it to its original value, because *you* changed it (when you ran the `.` command). But if the sourced script also changed it, then that should probably be allowed to persist.

Comment: @Kevin I'm confused. You restore the original PATH iff the sourced script did not set it. If the sourced script made no changes to PATH, why do you need to restore the original value?

Comment: @doneal24: As the question explains, when you write `PATH='...' . script.sh`, then that command permanently changes `PATH`, regardless of whether or not `script.sh` does anything to `PATH`. If `script.sh` did not change it, then you presumably want to undo your own assignment (i.e. that is what OP appears to be asking for). If `script.sh` did change it, then you presumably want that alteration to persist (or else why did you source it?). So you use an if statement to check whether `script.sh` changed `PATH`, and revert it to its original value if and only if `script.sh` did not change it.

Answer (score 16):

`.` is a [*special* builtin](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14).

Per POSIX:

> 2. As described in Simple Commands, variable assignments preceding the invocation of a special built-in utility remain in effect after the built-in completes; this shall not be the
> case with a regular built-in or other utility.

That particular requirement bash only honours when in POSIX mode like when invoked as `sh` (more generally, when its `posix` option is enabled).

To remove their *specialness* to a *special* builtin, in POSIX compliant shells, you can prefix them with `command` as [`command`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/command.html) itself is an ordinary builtin, not a *special* one. POSIX explicitly mentions:

> If the command_name is the same as the name of one of the special built-in utilities, the special properties in the enumerated list at the beginning of Special Built-In Utilities shall not occur. In every other respect, if command_name is not the name of a function, the effect of command (with no options) shall be the same as omitting command.

```
bash-5.1$ echo printenv PATH > file
bash-5.1$ (PATH=/; PATH=/usr/bin . ./file; echo "$PATH")
/usr/bin
/
bash-5.1$ set -o posix
bash-5.1$ (PATH=/; PATH=/usr/bin . ./file; echo "$PATH")
/usr/bin
/usr/bin
bash-5.1$ (PATH=/; PATH=/usr/bin command . ./file; echo "$PATH")
/usr/bin
/
```

In the case of special builtins such as `eval` or `.` though, it is a bit of an oversight by POSIX, as honouring that for those would kind of mean that in order to be able to restore `$var` after `var=value command . file` or `var=value command eval some-code`, the shell would have to implement some sort of variable stack and in effect local scope for variables, which POSIX doesn't otherwise specify. You'll find that in practice, it doesn't work with all `sh` implementations and in particular not ksh88 which the POSIX specification is based on.

Answer (score 3):

> How to temporarily set `$PATH` and `.` (source) a file, in the POSIX compliant way?

```
OPATH=$PATH PATH=...
. someSource
PATH=$OPATH
```

Comment: Is it impossible to do it within one statement?

Comment: I prefer this for simplicity. Create a new $PATH, and save the old one and restore it. You can put this script in /usr/local/bin or any suitable place. However, it may run into issues if the sourced script depends on a command (e.g. grep) in the old $PATH. For that reason I'd simply put PATH=$PATH:$NEWPATH in ~/.bashrc or a corresponding file in another shell, and have no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this answer applies to bash only. It doesn't work in fully POSIX-compliant shells.

> Is it impossible to do it within one statement?

Yes! Wrap it in a function. This approach does not need an extra variable (keep variable contamination minimum).

The sourced file:

```
$ cat script.sh 
echo "in script.sh file"

var='altered'
```

The sourcing file:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

var='original'

echo $PATH
echo
_() { . "$1" ; }

PATH="/tmp:${PATH}" _ script.sh
echo
echo $PATH
echo
echo "$var"
```

The `echo` statement in the sourced file, and the `$var` variable are used to verify the file `script.sh` is successfully sourced.

The altered `$PATH` is only valid within the function `_` (you may use a better name). `$PATH` is not altered after the statement.

Comment: No extra variable, but an extra function though.

Comment: This works in bash and zsh, and oddly also in dash, but it is not POSIX-compliant and doesn't work in ksh, `bash --posix`, zsh in sh or ksh emulation, or BusyBox ash. In POSIX-compliant shells, when `f` is a function, `VAR=value f` is equivalent to `VAR=value; f`, like with special builtins as explained in Stéphane's answer.

Comment: Oh really?! It is good to know that, in POSIX compliant shell, it treats functions differently as programs. Anywhere mentioned in the docs? I want to read more about these. Thanks.

Comment: [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/): “If the command name is a special built-in utility, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment. (…)  it is unspecified: (…)” (and next bullet point for functions). My bad, in recent POSIX versions this is unspecified, [Older versions of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_014) mandated the weird behavior that “Variable assignments specified with special built-in utilities will remain in effect after the built-in completes” (and same for functions).